# Craigslist Scraper using Scrapy Spider not performing functions

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

```
2021-05-07 10:07:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-05-07 10:07:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa/> (referer: None)
2021-05-07 10:07:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa?s=120> (referer: https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa/)
2021-05-07 10:07:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa?s=240> (referer: https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa?s=120)
```

this is the output I get, seems like it just moves to the page of results, performed by selecting the next button and performing a request in line 27

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, Request
from craig.items import CraigItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class PhonesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'phones'
    allowed_domains = ['tampa.craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa/']



    def parse(self, response):
        phones = response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')
        for phone in phones:
            relative_url = phone.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)
            title = phone.xpath('a/text()').extract_first()
            price = phone.xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li[3]/a/span').extract_first()
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'URL': absolute_url, 'Title': title, 'price': price})
            
        
        relative_next_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="button next"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_url = "https://tampa.craigslist.org" + relative_next_url
        yield Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)

            
            
    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = CraigItem()
        item["cl_id"] = response.meta.get('Title')
        item["price"] = response.meta.get
        absolute_url = response.meta.get('URL')
        
        yield{'URL': absolute_url, 'Title': title, 'price': price}
```

Seems like in my code, for phone in phones loop, doesn't run, which results in never running parse_item and continuing to requesting the next url, I am following some tutorials and reading documentation but im still having trouble grasping what I am doing wrong. I have experience with coding arduinos as a hobby when I was young, but no professional coding experience, this is my first forte into a project like this, I have an ok grasp on the basics of loops, functions, callbacks, etc.

any help is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

current output

```
2021-05-07 15:29:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-05-07 15:29:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa/> (referer: None)
2021-05-07 15:29:33 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/hil/mob/d/tampa-cut-that-high-cable-bill-switch/7309734640.html> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2021-05-07 15:29:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tampa.craigslist.org/hil/mob/d/tampa-cut-that-high-cable-bill-switch/7309734640.html> (referer: https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa/)
2021-05-07 15:29:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://tampa.craigslist.org/hil/mob/d/tampa-cut-that-high-cable-bill-switch/7309734640.html>
{'cl_id': 'postid_7309734640',
 'price': '$35',
 'title': 'Cut that high cable bill, switch to SPC TV and save. 1400 hd '
          'channels',
 'url': 'https://tampa.craigslist.org/hil/mob/d/tampa-cut-that-high-cable-bill-switch/7309734640.html'}
2021-05-07 15:29:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

**CURRENT CODE**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, Request
from craig.items import CraigItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class PhonesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'phones'
    allowed_domains = ['tampa.craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['https://tampa.craigslist.org/d/cell-phones/search/moa/']
    base_url = 'https://tampa.craigslist.org'
    



    def parse(self, response):
        phones = response.xpath('//div[@class="result-info"]')
        
        for phone in phones:
        
            x = response.meta.get('x')
            n = -1
            
            url = response.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').getall()
            relative_url = phone.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').get()
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)
            title = phone.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/text()').getall()
            price = phone.xpath('//span[@class="result-price"]/text()').getall()
            cl_id = phone.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@id').getall()
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'absolute_url': absolute_url, 'url': url, 'title': title, 'price': price, 'cl_id': cl_id, 'n': n})
        
            
        

            
            
    def parse_item(self, response):
        n = response.meta.get('n')
        x = n + 1
        
        item = CraigItem()
        item["title"] = response.meta.get('title')[x]
        item["cl_id"] = response.meta.get('cl_id')[x]
        item["price"] = response.meta.get('price')[x]
        item["url"] = response.meta.get('url')[x]

        yield item
        
        absolute_next_url = response.meta.get('url')[x]
        absolute_url = response.meta.get('absolute_url')
        
        yield Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'x': x})
```

I am now able to retrieve the desired content for a posting, URL, Price, Title and craigslist id, now my spider automatically closes after pulling just 1 result, I am having trouble understanding the process of using variables between the 2 functions (x) and (n), logically, after pulling one listings data, as above in the format

cl_id
Price
title
url

I would like to proceed back to the initial parse function and swap to the next item in the list of urls retrieved by

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').getall()
```

which (when run in scrapy shell, succesfully pulls all the URLs)

how do I go about implementing this logic of start with [0] in the list, perform parse, perform parse_item, output item, then update a variable (n which starts as 0, needs to + 1 after each item)then call n in parse_item with its updated value and use, for example `(item["title"] = response.meta.get('title')[x])` to refer to the list of urls, etc, and which place to select, then run parse_item again outputting 1 at a time, until all the values in the URL list have been output with their related price, cl_id, and title.

I know the code is messy as hell and the basics aren't fully understood by me yet, but im committed to getting this to work and learning it the hard way rather than starting from the ground up for python.

Answer (score 0):

Class `result-info` is used within the `div` block, so you should write:

```
phones = response.xpath('//div[@class="result-info"]')
```

That being said, I didn't check/fix your spider further (it seems there are only parsing errors, not functional ones).
As a suggestion for the future, you can use Scrapy shell for quickly debugging the issues:

```
scrapy shell "your-url-here"
```

Comment: Thank you, updated the post with my current problems, scrapy shell definitely helped figure out the xpaths and understand how to target them, now to proceed with breaking the code again until one day it works as intended.